# Sprockets::FileNotFound in Application#angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm working through the thinkster Angular-Rails tutorial (https://thinkster.io/angular-rails), and encounter the following error trying to install Devise:

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Application#angular

```
couldn't find file 'angular-devise'(in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js:2)
```

I have installed Devise gem, restarted the server, installed angular-devise and injected Devise module into my app.  Guidance on how to troubleshoot appreciated!

Comment: I'm following the same tutorial. The bower install of angular-devise has changed. It is now AngularDevise. Earlier on in the tutorial he says you can include items as long as they look the same in the bower.json file. You should accepts Ravi's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of angular-devise use AngularDevise/lib/devise but it must be placed after
angular-rails-templates
please see the following order

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require AngularDevise/lib/devise
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @Stevo ,  when i installed angular-devise in my rails app, folder name under bower_component is AngularDevise.

Answer (score 2):

Ravi's approach worked for me.

The step from the thinkster tutorial reads like this:
*require angular-devise in application.js after angular*

Seems like the wording of that step could be improved.

Note that the AngularDevise folder contains a bower.json file that points to lib/devise.js.  So this will also work:

```
//= require AngularDevise
```

Doing it this way is more consistent with how other packages are referenced in the application.js file.  And it insulates application.js from future changes to the directory structure/naming inside the AngularDevise directory.